# Eclipse showing error

Tags: android

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2014-11-09 22:45:05.351
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.LinkageError: Error reading class bytes: org.eclipse.jface.action.ExternalActionManager$CommandCallback
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findClassImpl(ClasspathManager.java:552)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClassImpl(ClasspathManager.java:492)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:465)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:216)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:395)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.SingleSourcePackage.loadClass(SingleSourcePackage.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:461)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.initializeCommandResolver(Workbench.java:1495)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.initializeDefaultServices(Workbench.java:2123)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.init(Workbench.java:1407)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$36(Workbench.java:1368)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$57.run(Workbench.java:2522)
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid literal/lengths set
    at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.bundlefile.ZipBundleEntry$ZipBundleEntryInputStream.read(ZipBundleEntry.java:157)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.AdaptorUtil.getBytes(AdaptorUtil.java:247)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.bundlefile.BundleEntry.getBytes(BundleEntry.java:96)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findClassImpl(ClasspathManager.java:548)
    ... 15 more
```

Comment: What is your question and what have you tried so far to resolve the issue?

Comment: show codes and also elaborate what you doing

Comment: eclipse not opened.its showing:- an error ocured see log file.

Comment: I delete .snap but still its not working